# How to change a css color variable lightness?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

Context:
I have a project whose colors are coming from the backend before app is mounted, I'm setting these colors to some variables and I'm using these variables to set colors for texts and buttons.
But Currently I want to have a hover version from this color (make it lighter or darker), how can I accomplish this using scss?.

Comment: I don't think SCSS would be a solution for this since you need a compilation step and the colors are fetched on demand. I'd use plain CSS and JavaScript for this.

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero Thank you for replaying, could please explain to me how this can be done in javascript ?

Comment: Go to the SASS webpage and look at the color functions https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color

Answer (score 1):

You can use `darken(colour, percentage)` or `lighten()` as seen below:

`.class:hover {background: darken($colour, 10%)}`

See https://falkus.co/2017/05/using-lighten-and-darken-in-sass/ for more info

Comment: thank you, I've tried it right now and I got an error message saying `SassError: $color: var(--first-base-color) is not a color.`, I think this because I'm dynamically setting these color variables from backend to my css then using these variables within scss files, so it's not knowing yet it will be a colour, however it worked with hardcoded colors as $greyColor: #eee.

Answer (score 0):

For CSS hover you'd want something like:

```
class:hover
```

for the colour, you'd want to use RGBA.

try something like:
class{ color: red;}
class:hover { color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)}

In the example, the 255 value = the colour red, and the 0.5 value is the opacity. It can range from 0 to 1 with 1 being fully solid.
It would mean looking to see what your chosen colour would be in rgba though... e.g violet is (238,130,238)

Colour value is self explanatory really due to the initials of RGB, but just in case: red = first value, Green = second, Blue = third.